# Manually Write Stream Without CHUNKED Response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome

I am trying to manually write my response stream and close it so that I can continue doing some stuff after the response is closed.  I acheive this successfully by doing the following:

```
Response.StatusCode = 200
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
Response.Write(j)
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
DOWORK()
```

This works perfect in most instances, however for Chrome / Flash, there is a bug in flash were it is causing this to assume it's an IO error.  When analyzing the headers, the difference between manually sending a response with Return Json(results) and how I did it above is that when I return the data normally it uses a header of:

```
Content-Length: 44
```

Where as when I send it with the code above I get:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Is it possible to do what I want but not have the data chunked?  I know this is not ASP.net specific, rather a bug in flash for chrome, but I would like to solve this.

Comment: Why can't you use "return Json(obj);" MVC helper instead of manual response? You can implement your own ActionResult inheriting from JsonResult to add some work after Execute method will be called

Comment: If I do "Return JSON(obj)" the method stops executing there.  I understand your response says I can inherit from ActionResult to continue after the fact, but not sure how I would do that?  Only way I can think is to maybe start a background worker before returning the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment, I was thinking about something like:

```
public class CustomResult : JsonResult
{
    private Action afterAction;
    private object obj = null;

    public CustomResult(object obj, Action afterAction) : base()
    {
        this.JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        this.Data = obj;
        this.afterAction = afterAction;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
        afterAction();
    }
}
```

Now you could call it in controller action:

```
return new CustomResult(obj, () => { //custom code here, will be executed later });
```

Comment: I sadly do not have time to test this right now. Was asking for future testing, however I will mark it as complete because as long as it works as outlined, where base.ExecuteResult(context) closes the connection, it should do exactly as I need.  Thanks!